# Barbutton item in navigtion bar leftbar button got stick to the top left conrner

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

bar button got stick to the y origin as 0 to navigation bar and x as 0.but i want to add some y position to barbutton item.

```
 UIBarButtonItem *barbutton;

            barbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(onbackbtnpressed:)];
            [barbutton setWidth:30];
            [barbutton setTintColor:KANEKA_BLUE_COLOR];
            [barbutton setAccessibilityFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 20)];
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbutton;
```

Please tell me how can i set the barbutton frame or how to set the bar button y position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My views about this question - As per iOS Human Interface Guidelines it is not recommended to add y spacing for the bar button items on navigation bar.

We can update x positioning by setting an array of buttons for navigation item as shown below:

```
  UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpaceBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
  [fixedSpaceBarButton setWidth:10];

  UIBarButtonItem *barbutton;

  barbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(onbackbtnpressed:)];
  [barbutton setWidth:30];
  [barbutton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  [barbutton setAccessibilityFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 20)];

  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray
                                            arrayWithObjects:fixedSpaceBarButton, barbutton, nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have managed to set the y origin in little bit different way may be it is big procedure but it is quite good.

I have added a toolbar to viewcontroller and set the bar button item and hidden the navigation bar.And it works for all the popover controllers.

```
self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width-100,self.view.frame.size.height-100);
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        [self.toolbar setTintColor:KANEKA_BLUE_COLOR];
        [self.backbutton setTintColor:KANEKA_BLUE_COLOR];
```