# Space issue with UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to add a `Cancel` UIBarButtonItem to my navigation bar using following code:

```
func setupNavBar() {
    self.navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 64.0))

    let customNavigationItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Connect Accounts")
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, target: self, action: "cancelClicked")
    customNavigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(cancelButton, animated: true)

    self.navBar.setItems([customNavigationItem], animated: true)

    self.view.addSubview(self.navBar)
}
```

The bar button is appearing completely sticked to the screen edge as follow:

[image]

Why is this button appearing sticked to the edge of screen and how can I give it spacing so that it does not sticks there? Please help!

EDIT: My button is sticked to just left edge of screen and not to the top-left corner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Barbutton item in navigtion bar leftbar button got stick to the top left conrner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509689/barbutton-item-in-navigtion-bar-leftbar-button-got-stick-to-the-top-left-conrner)

Comment: @BadalShah in the question mentioned by you, the questioner's button is sticked to top-left corner. In the screen shot provided by me, we can see that is sticked to only left edge and not top-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to add space is using .FixedSpace :

```
let fixedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
fixedSpace.width = 10
customNavigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [fixedSpace, cancelButton]
```

> UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
>
> Blank space to add between other
>   items. Only the width property is used when this value is set.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: I did use your answer yesterday and it worked great! One weird thing happening is that today I tried removing that `fixedSpace` item and it is working fine. I am completely clueless why is this weird thing happening.

Comment: Ok, I have observed that if both, right and left bar button items are set then the spacing appears proper, else we have to add the fixed space bar button item!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(<your margin>, 0, 50, 44))
        btn.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlStateNormal)

       let btnbarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn)
        customNavigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(btnbarButton, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.setupNavBar()
    }
    func setupNavBar() {

        let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 64.0))
    let customNavigationItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Connect Accounts")
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, target: self, action: "cancelClicked:")
    let fixedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    fixedSpace.width = 10
    customNavigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [fixedSpace, cancelButton]

    navBar.setItems([customNavigationItem], animated: true)

    self.view.addSubview(navBar)
    }

    func cancelClicked(sender: AnyObject){
        print("Good luck!")
    }
```